# How does vi editor remember current line of the previous file

Tags: editor, vi

Suppose I am reading a file in vi editor. I am at line number 50 and I quit. After some time I reopen the file in vi editor. I notice that the cursor is at the same line where I was before closing the file.
How does VI editor remember this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about plain old `vi`.  `vim`, however, saves the current line number of the files you edit with it in a file called `.viminfo` in your home directory.  At least, that's what it does in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this behavior in many programs. You close your IDE and when you reopen it, it opens your last project. Your can kill your firefox and when you reopen it, you get all your pages reloaded.

It is simple, they save it somewhere for themselves.

One of the common places to save these information in Windows-y applications is the registry. You can run `regedt32` in your windows and see all those data there. With Linux-y applications, it is common to create a hidden file in your home (`~`). You can go to your home directory in your Linux and open file `.bash_history` and see your old bash commands that you can access with the `Up Arrow` key

Vi in particular? Definitely has a file somewhere.

Comment: So you mean to say that it maintains some cache kind of things for itself.If so, can we clear them manually or it is done automatically.

Comment: It most certainly does. To clear it, you have to look up the manual. I use ViM (not Vi) and I know there is an option to disable this feature (and I'm sure in Vi it should exist too). Perhaps disabling and re-enabling the feature would flush the cache. Otherwise, you could take a look in your home directory (in Linux, `~` and in Windows, `documents and settings\your name` and see if there is a hidden file with vi or vim name in it and look at them, see what they contain. Then, you could delete parts of the cache